# Python gettext: convert Unicode literals into text

Tags: python, windows, unicode, internationalization, gettext

I work in Windows. Python 2.7.2
I have a module in which i have to translate a few messages with gettext.
So i create UTF-8 no BOM *.po file, make *.mo out of it and use code like this:

```
 t = gettext.translation('index','./locale',  languages=['ru'])
_= t.ugettext
t.install()
```

As a result i have something like this:

```
(u'\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430')
```

How to covert it into common UTF-8 text?

Comment: Where are you trying to display this text?

Comment: in console through print. if i display it into web template, everything goes fine.

Comment: For the simplest usage, using `print` function will output text in the related encoding. So `print u'\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430'` will give a readable output.

Comment: gettext already sends u'...' to print

Comment: What _exact_ output are you getting, and what _exact_ output did you expect to get?

Comment: nope.. actually I get translated text in my web interface, but if i try to print it into console I get "\x012" or "u'\u0431" stuff

Comment: @AlexNasonov - So... have you solved this question? Was my answer of any use? If yes, please upvote, if not let me know and I will delete it! :)

Comment: i can't upvote )) not enough rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to covert it into common UTF-8 text?

This is the wrong question. :) It is already UTF-8 text... What you are trying to understand is how to display it as alphabetical characters. This should be automatic in anything that uses strings as visual output. The easiest case, the `print` function (or statement).

```
>>> print u'\u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430'
системная ошибка
```